# onkeyup or onclick JavaScript to auto submit form

Tags: javascript, html

Any onkeyup or onclick javascript code which helps me to submit form after 9 characters.

MY HTML CODE. I am using AJAX to get data. I have tried many scripts. None works for me :'(

```
Enter Your Car No : <input type="text" name="car"  maxlength="9" id="carno" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST["carno"]; ?>"/>
```

Comment: can you show that scripts you tried with?

Comment: You want to submit your form when you enter 9 characters in a textbox,Right?

Comment: Why did the other script not work for you? What were you missing? Or what went wrong? What did you try?

Comment: Can you at least understand JavaScript or is this a request to do your work?

Comment: Did you try anything,Or at least search for any solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
Enter Your Car No : <input type="text" name="car"  maxlength="9" id="carno" onkeypress="yourFunction()" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST["carno"]; ?>"/>

<script>
function yourFunction(){
  var textValue = document.getElementById('carno').value;
  if(textValue.length >= 9){
       //implement your ajax code
  }
}
</script>


Hai here i am calling function on each key press in that text field and i am getting the value using id and checking that length if its >=9 (ur requirement) so write ajax code
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Enter Your Car No : <input type="text" name="car"  maxlength="9" id="carno" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST["carno"]; ?>" onkeypress="submitForm()" onclick="submitForm()"/>
<script>
   function submitForm(){
       var len = document.getElementById("carno").value.length;
       if(len >= 9 ){
           //submit form code
       }else{
           return false;
       }
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Not from what I can tell..  There is still one more.